# Gemfile causes torquebox env variables to come up empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby, jrubyonrails, torquebox

I think I've found a bug in torquebox. For some reason, if I "gem install torquebox" and then add a "gem 'torquebox'" line to my Gemfile, "torquebox env" stops working properly. This is very easy to reproduce, so if anyone knows what's going on please let me know:

To reproduce the bug, let's create a new gemset and install torquebox-server

```
$ rvm use jruby-1.6.7.2
$ rvm gemset create test
$ mkdir torquetest
$ cd torquetest
$ rvm use jruby-1.6.7.2@test
```

Let me pause for a moment to show you what's in my jruby-1.6.7.2@global, in case that matters:

```
$ ls ~/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7.2@global/gems 
total 0
drwxr-xr-x   9 jstokes   306 Aug  9 16:26 ./
drwxr-xr-x   7 jstokes   238 Aug  9 16:25 ../
drwxr-xr-x   5 jstokes   170 Aug  9 16:25 bouncy-castle-java-1.5.0146.1/
drwxr-xr-x  15 jstokes   510 Aug  9 16:26 bundler-1.1.5/
drwxr-xr-x  34 jstokes  1156 Aug  9 16:25 jruby-launcher-1.0.15-java/
drwxr-xr-x  10 jstokes   340 Aug  9 16:25 jruby-openssl-0.7.7/
drwxr-xr-x  13 jstokes   442 Aug  9 16:25 rake-0.9.2.2/
drwxr-xr-x  14 jstokes   476 Aug  9 16:26 rubygems-bundler-1.0.5/
drwxr-xr-x   8 jstokes   272 Aug  9 16:26 rvm-1.11.3.5/
```

Anyway, continuing on:

```
$ gem install torquebox-server
$ torquebox env

TORQUEBOX_HOME=/Users/jstokes/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7.2@test/gems/torquebox-server-2.1.2-java
JBOSS_HOME=/Users/jstokes/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7.2@test/gems/torquebox-server-2.1.2-java/jboss
JRUBY_HOME=/Users/jstokes/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.6.7.2
```

So far so good, right? Now here's where it goes south:

```
$ echo "gem 'torquebox'" > Gemfile
$ torquebox env

TORQUEBOX_HOME=
JBOSS_HOME=/jboss
JRUBY_HOME=/Users/jstokes/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.6.7.2
```

And now the vars are broken, so I can't use torquebox. If I delete the "gem 'torquebox'" line from the Gemfile, it works fine again, however, it messes up my rails deployment to torquebox. Any ideas?

(PS: This happens on OS X 10.8.2 and OS X 10.7.5. I'm using the latest version of ZSH with iTerm, and RVM is updated to the latest stable release as of today.)

**Update:** "bundle exec torquebox env" doesn't work either, FYI :(

Comment: Confirmed banzaiman's answer on jruby 1.6.7 & 1.6.7.2

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You only have `torquebox` in `Gemfile`; you'll need to use `torquebox-server` instead (since `torquebox` is a dependency of `torquebox-server`).

```
$ bundle show
Gems included by the bundle:
  * blankslate (2.1.2.4)
  * bundler (1.2.1)
  * clj (0.0.5.6)
  * rake (0.9.2.2)
  * thor (0.16.0)
  * torquebox (2.1.2)
  * torquebox-cache (2.1.2)
  * torquebox-configure (2.1.2)
  * torquebox-core (2.1.2)
  * torquebox-messaging (2.1.2)
  * torquebox-naming (2.1.2)
  * torquebox-rake-support (2.1.2)
  * torquebox-security (2.1.2)
  * torquebox-server (2.1.2)
  * torquebox-stomp (2.1.2)
  * torquebox-transactions (2.1.2)
  * torquebox-web (2.1.2)
$ torquebox env
TORQUEBOX_HOME=/Users/asari/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.8@torquebox/gems/torquebox-server-2.1.2-java
JBOSS_HOME=/Users/asari/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.8@torquebox/gems/torquebox-server-2.1.2-java/jboss
JRUBY_HOME=/Users/asari/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.6.8
```

Comment: This is apparently the right answer. I need to email Joe Kutner and tell him that the bug is actually in "Deploying JRuby" :)

Comment: @JonStokes You might want to submit an erratum: http://pragprog.com/titles/jkdepj/errata